# Zilean bombs, shield the placement or the explosion?

Tags: league-of-legends

While playing a character with a spellshield (Nocturne or Sivir) do you need to shield the bomb's placement or the bomb's explosion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spell sheilds do not stop the actual explosion, however Zilean can't place a bomb on you if you have your spell sheild on.

Comment: Does Banshee's Veil work the same way?

Comment: Yes, it does @bbz.

Answer (score -1):

As already said, every spellshield (nocs, Sivirs) shields the PLACEMENT, and so does banshees. The only things that shield the explosion/the dmg are Morgs Black Shield and Hexdrinkers Shield.

Comment: Uhm, Sions shield blocks damage. Every shield that blocks damage can hold off the explosion, so not only Morgs black shield and Hexdrinker.

Comment: Also Janna's shield, or mordekaisers

Comment: Shen Rumble Malphite Lux Lee sin Lulu Oriana // Solaris

Comment: Karma blitz Nautilus Riven Skarner Udyr Urgot Viktor

Comment: its about only magic shields. not shields in general.